# SQL AND and OR logic error

Tags: sql, ms-access, boolean-logic

Using MS Access 2016

Very stuck on a query error. It only is using either the "Milestone" criteria or the "HierarchyLevel" criteria - depending on which control was updated last. The Status criteria works in all cases.

Can anyone see my error? The query should meet the criteria of: chosen Status, Milestone Name search string, chosen level or Null level (ie all Levels)

Thanks Kindly

```
SELECT
qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.ID, 
qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.HierarchyLevel, 
qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.Milestone 

FROM qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy 
WHERE 
    (  qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.Milestone Like   "*" & [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![txt_SearchTerm].[Text] & "*"  ) 
AND (  qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.IDStatus               = [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_Status]  )
AND 
(
       qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.HierarchyLevel         = [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_HierarchyLevel] 
 OR
       Len( [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_HierarchyLevel].[Text] & "" ) = 0 
)
;
```

**UPDATE**

Example Date

```
HierarchyLevel     Milestone
4                  NameTest1
4                  NameDemo1
3                  NameTest2
3                  NameDemo2
```

When I only use the Milestone or the Level filter I get the correct results

```
Controls 
TextBox(Milestone)        = ""
CombboBox(Status)         = 1
CombboBox(HierarchyLevel) = 4

Results
HierarchyLevel     Milestone
4                  NameTest1
4                  NameDemo1
```

Level 3 records are wrongly being included in the result

```
Controls 
TextBox(Milestone)        = "Test"
CombboBox(Status)         = 1
CombboBox(HierarchyLevel) = 4

Results
HierarchyLevel     Milestone
4                  NameTest1
3                  NameTest2
```

Comment: Are you actually getting an error, or just incorrect results? If so, what's the error?

Comment: Incorrect results. I cannot fathom why

Comment: It would also help to post an example of the current results you are getting and your desired results.

Comment: If I modify the query to include only the first or second half of the OR statement then the results are as expected. When I include both with the OR statement the results are as described above.

Comment: Shouldn't this statement `qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.HierarchyLevel         = [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_HierarchyLevel]` also include `.Text`  on the `cbo`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `Len( [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_HierarchyLevel].[Text] & "" ) = 0` That is kind of a clunky statement and seems to be the root of your problem. What do you want that to do?

Comment: Just to confirm I have tried the .Text extension in all reasonable places to no avail. I used it only to accommodate pointing to the right control property when trigging a one line vba code that re-queries the list box that stores the query results.

Comment: @SandPiper I include that line so that the user can select all levels at once and then use a text string to search. users may not know at what level their record is stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a IIf to switch the last statement. Note that the use of wildcards at the beginning of a search renders indexing on the field redundant so large datasets will make this very slow.

```
SELECT
qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.ID, 
qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.HierarchyLevel, 
qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.Milestone 

FROM qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy 
WHERE ( qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.Milestone Like   "*" & [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![txt_SearchTerm] & "*"  ) 
AND ( qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.IDStatus               = [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_Status]  )
AND ( qry_Milestones_WithHierarchy.HierarchyLevel  " & IIF ([Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_HierarchyLevel] is null ,"Like *", " = " & [Forms]![frm_SelectMilestone]![cbo_HierarchyLevel] ) & ") ;
```

Comment: Wonderful innovation. Thank you. I had to delete the "=" sign before the IIf statement, but it does exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Oh and Regarding indexing, that's good to know but the Milestones field can contain duplicte names, including at the same level. It is not indexed

Comment: I noticed the extra = after I posted , and have edited the answer.